# Achieve real parallelism python C-Extension

Tags: python, multithreading, python-c-extension

I have written a python C Extension. Its working fine. But Now for more efficient execution, I need to write a multithreaded/parallel-executing version of the same extension.

Can you please tell me, how to write a Python C-Extension code that runs on multiple cores at the same time.

I have struck here for more than day. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

maybe too late but hope helps other people:)

simplest way to parallel executing of C extension is using [OPENMP](http://openmp.org/wp/) API.  from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP):

> OpenMP (Open Multi-Processing) is an application programming interface
>   (API) that supports multi-platform shared memory multiprocessing
>   programming in C, C++, and Fortran, on most platforms, processor
>   architectures and operating systems.

for example see this part of code:

```
int i;
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    printf("%d ",i);
}
```

result:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

we can make it parallel using `#pragma omp parallel for` compiler directive before `for` statement block:

```
int i;
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    printf("%d ",i);
}
```

result:

```
0 1 5 8 9 2 6 4 3 7
```

to enabling openmp in gcc you need to specify `-fopenmp` compile-time flag. Example:

```
gcc -fPIC -Wall -O3 costFunction.c -o costFunction.so -shared -fopenmp
```

you can lean openmp from [HERE](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/).

> the are other ways like [pthread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads) but it is very low-level.

**OpenMP vs. PThread:**
example from [HERE](http://www.futurechips.org/tips-for-power-coders/open-mp-pthreads.html) written in C++.

***serial C++ code:***

```
void sum_st(int *A, int *B, int *C){
   int end = 10000000;
   for(int i = 0; i < end; i++)
    A[i] = B[i] + C[i];
}
```

***pthread solution:***

```
 struct params {
  int *A;
  int *B;
  int *C;
  int tid;
  int size;
  int nthreads;
};

void *compute_parallel(void *_p){
  params *p      = (params*) _p;
  int tid        = p->tid;
  int chunk_size = (p->size / p->nthreads);
  int start      = tid * chunk_size;
  int end        = start + chunk_size;
  for(int i = start; i < end; i++)     p->A[i] = p->B[i] + p->C[i];
  return 0;
}

void sum_mt(int *A, int *B, int *C){
  int nthreads = 4;
  int size = 10000000;
  pthread_t threads[nthreads]; //array to hold thread information
  params *thread_params = (params*) malloc(nthreads * sizeof(params));

  for(int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++){
    thread_params[i].A        = A;
    thread_params[i].B        = B;
    thread_params[i].C        = C;
    thread_params[i].tid      = i;
    thread_params[i].size     = size;
    thread_params[i].nthreads = nthreads;
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, compute_parallel, (void*) &thread_params[i]);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++){
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
  }
  free(thread_params);

}
```

***OpenMP solution:***

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
  A[i] = B[i] + C[i];
```